# Rune game development, issues with the game logic and App design

Tags: typescript

Need help with my components

I tried adding to the interface and since typescript has certain rules, the variables are not being recognized. The logic and App Component are not working with the main component. I have do not see where I am going wrong.

```
export interface GameState {
scores: Record<string, number>;
punches: number;
jumps: number;
fighting: boolean;
dodging: boolean;
```

}

```
type GameActions = {
incrementScore: (params: { playerWhoGotPoints: string }) => void;
incrementPunches: (params: { playerId: string }) => void;
incrementJumps: (params: { playerId: string }) => void;
startFight: () => void;
startDodge: () => void;
endFightOrDodge: () => void;
```

};

```
Rune.initLogic({
minPlayers: 1,
maxPlayers: 4,
setup: (allPlayerIds: string[]) => {
  const scores: Record<string, number> = {};
  for (let playerId of allPlayerIds) {
    scores[playerId] = 0;
  }
  const game: GameState = {
    scores,
    punches: 0,
    jumps: 0,
    fighting: false,
    dodging: false,
  };
  return game;



},
actions: {
  incrementScore(playerWhoGotPoints: string, { game }) {
    game.scores[playerWhoGotPoints]++;
  },
  incrementPunches({ playerId: string }, { game }) {
    game.punches++;
    game.scores[playerId]++;
  },
  incrementJumps({ playerId: string }, { game }) {
    game.jumps++;
    game.scores[playerId]++;
  },
  startFight({}, { game }) {
    game.fighting = true;
  },
  startDodge({}, { game }) {
    game.dodging = true;
  },
  endFightOrDodge({}, { game }) {
    game.fighting = false;
    game.dodging = false;
  },
},
events: {
  playerJoined: (playerId: string, { game }) => {
    game.scores[playerId] = 0;
  },
},
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Wherr in the code? Also, it looks like your code is missing the `})` for `Rune.initLogic({`

Comment: playerId object is not being defined. The bigger errors are in the startFight, startDodge endFifghtOrDodge with their empty curly braces.


Which is also affecting my app objects

 Rune.initClient({
      onChange: ({ newGame, players, yourPlayerId })

Also when I run npm run dev, I get this error  361 │ import Rune from "rune-games-sdk";

which makes no sense as I have that import at the top of the module.